# How to call TinyTeX from text editors (command line)?

Tags: r

I use some editors like TeXstudio, etc., and they work with "command line" commands like (example with TeXstudio and pdflatex):

```
pdflatex --shell-escape %.tex
```

In this case, `%` is a variable for the file name.

In R's `tinytex` it is possible to use the command line as the example below

```
Rscript -e 'tinytex::pdflatex(file)'
```

where `file` is a fully specified file name (e.g `home/user/Desktop/test.tex`). My question is: how to pass a variable instead of `file` to TinyTeX so it works with text editors?

Comment: Try `commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)[1]` instead of `file` and then call it like `Rscript -e 'tinytex::pdflatex(commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)[1])' /path/tp/file.tex`.  I don't speak R though, I just copied that from here https://swcarpentry.github.io/r-novice-inflammation/05-cmdline/

Comment: Yay, it works! Thank you very much